# UILocalNotification failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

The local notification never appeared. Can somebody tell me why?

```
- (IBAction)addReminder:(id)sender {
    self.datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName: @"Asia/Tokyo"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *formatedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
    NSLog(@"formatedDate>>>>>：%@", formatedDate);
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:formatedDate];

    NSTimeZone *zone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    NSInteger interval = [zone secondsFromGMTForDate: date];
    NSDate *localeDate = [date  dateByAddingTimeInterval: interval];
    NSLog(@"Setting a reminder for %@", localeDate);


    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotif. fireDate = localeDate;
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.alertBody = @"ZEIT!";
    localNotif.alertAction = @"Show me the Timer!";
    localNotif.timeZone = zone;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] +1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

Result:

```
formatedDate>>>>>：2015-08-09 23:32:00 Setting a reminder for 2015-08-09 23:32:00 +0000
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your post to explain exactly what you want this program to return, as it's not entirely clear from the question and it's vital for understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are requesting permission from the user to show notifications.

```
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To : kmcgrady , thanks for your answer, but i tried this and it worked

```
NSDate *now=[NSDate new];
localNotif.fireDate=[now dateByAddingTimeInterval:12];
```